# Redirecting DMA memory access

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mmu

I'm wondering if it is possible to redirect memory reading requests of a DMA device to another address on the OS level without the DMA device being noticed.

Let's say my PCIe card can access all the memory on my PC by directly reading the physical addresses. Can the MMU of the operating system redirect these requests to other addresses in 
memory? That means the DMA address thinks it reads the correct physical addresses, but actually it is reading some other addresses?

Is that possible?

Comment: No, the MMU is limited to the CPU only on most common architectures that I know of. Why do you need to do this anyway? Are you trying to prevent attacks like [Inception](http://www.breaknenter.org/projects/inception/)?

Comment: You need an IOMMU for that. Not all PCs have one.